# sommer, multivariate liner mixed model analysis, plant breeding applications

Tags: r, mixed-models

I had the opportunity to read the sommer documentation but I was able to find some example of regression on markers (rrBLUP parametrization), just examples using the kinship parametrization (GBLUP parametrization). Please, could you gently say if it is possible
 on sommer to regress directly on markers, instead of using the kinship matrix? Especially under multivariate scenarios (multiple traits, locations etc) modelling an unstructured var-cov for the marker effects

Answer (score 0):

In sommer >= 3.7 is straight forward to fit an rrBLUP model in the multivariate setting, the DT_cpdata has a good example

```
librayr(sommer)
data(DT_cpdata)
mix.rrblup <- mmer(fixed=cbind(color,Yield)~1,
                   random=~vs(list(GT),Gtc=unsm(2)) + vs(Rowf,Gtc=diag(2))
                   rcov=~vs(units,Gtc=unsm(2)),
                   data=DT)
summary(mix.rrblup)

A <- A.mat(GT)
mix.gblup <- mmer(fixed=cbind(color,Yield)~1,
                  random=~vs(id,Gu=A, Gtc=unsm(2)) + vs(Rowf,Gtc=diag(2))
                  rcov=~vs(units,Gtc=unsm(2)),
                  data=DT)
summary(mix.gblup)
```

the vs() function makes a variance structure for a given random effect, and the covariance structure for the univariate/multivariate setting is provided in the Gtc argument as a matrix, where i.e. diagonal, unstructured or a customized structure can be provided. When the user want to provide a customized matrix as a random effect such as a marker matrix GT to do rrBLUP it has to be provided in a list() to internally help sommer to put it in the right format, whereas in the GBLUP version the random effect id which has the labels for individuals can have a covariance matrix provided in the Gu argument.